# Background coloring in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse

The background of eclipse editor (java or javascript editor) can be changed as well as the selected area through the preferences.  But I want to set background of a selected scope in a  code (not the highlighted background). For instance, assume, if there are few methods in the code and I want to set different colors to the backgrounds of each method scope.

Is this supported in eclipse(Luna, Kepler) or some one know any opensource plugin which does this job ?